# Deploying a Random Forest Model on Amazon Sagemaker always getting a UnexpectedStatusException with Reason: AlgorithmError

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, amazon-sagemaker

Hey I am trying to deploy my RandomForest Classifier on Amazon Sagemaker but get a StatusException Error even though the script worked fine before:

The script runs fine and prints out the confusion matrix and accuracy as expected. When I try to deploy the model to amazon Sagemaker using the script it does not work.

```
! python script.py --n-estimators 100 \
                   --max_depth 2 \
                   --model-dir ./ \
                   --train ./ \
                   --test ./ \
```

Confusion Matrix:
[[13  8]
[ 1 17]]
Accuracy:
0.7692307692307693

I used the Estimator from Sagemaker Python SDK

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn
sklearn_estimator = SKLearn(
    entry_point='script.py',
    role = get_execution_role(),
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
    framework_version='0.20.0',
    base_job_name='rf-scikit')
```

I launched the training job as follows

```
sklearn_estimator.fit({'train':trainpath, 'test': testpath}, wait=False)
```

Here I am trying to deploy the model which leads to the StatusExceptionError that I cannot seem to fix

```
sklearn_estimator.latest_training_job.wait(logs='None')
artifact = m_boto3.describe_training_job(
    TrainingJobName=sklearn_estimator.latest_training_job.name)['ModelArtifacts']['S3ModelArtifacts']

print('Model artifact persisted at ' + artifact)
```

```
2022-08-25 12:03:27 Starting - Starting the training job....
2022-08-25 12:03:52 Starting - Preparing the instances for training............
2022-08-25 12:04:55 Downloading - Downloading input data......
2022-08-25 12:05:31 Training - Downloading the training image.........
2022-08-25 12:06:22 Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress..
2022-08-25 12:06:32 Uploading - Uploading generated training model.
2022-08-25 12:06:43 Failed - Training job failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-628f942a78d3> in <module>
----> 1 sklearn_estimator.latest_training_job.wait(logs='None')
      2 artifact = m_boto3.describe_training_job(
      3     TrainingJobName=sklearn_estimator.latest_training_job.name)['ModelArtifacts']['S3ModelArtifacts']
      4 
      5 print('Model artifact persisted at ' + artifact)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in wait(self, logs)
   2109             self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True, log_type=logs)
   2110         else:
-> 2111             self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)
   2112 
   2113     def describe(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in wait_for_job(self, job, poll)
   3226             lambda last_desc: _train_done(self.sagemaker_client, job, last_desc), None, poll
   3227         )
-> 3228         self._check_job_status(job, desc, "TrainingJobStatus")
   3229         return desc
   3230 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
   3390                 message=message,
   3391                 allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
-> 3392                 actual_status=status,
   3393             )
   3394 

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job rf-scikit-2022-08-25-12-03-25-931: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 84, in train
    entrypoint()
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/training.py", line 39, in main
    train(environment.Environment())
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/training.py", line 35, in train
    runner_type=runner.ProcessRunnerType)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/entry_point.py", line 100, in run
    wait, capture_error
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/process.py", line 291, in run
    cwd=environment.code_dir,
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_training/process.py", line 208, in check_error
    info=extra_info,
sagemaker_training.errors.ExecuteUserScriptError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
ExitCode 1
ErrorMessage ""
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python script.py"

ExecuteUserScriptErr
```

I am happy for some help

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your script? In the mean-time here is a working Sklearn Random Forest example that you can use as a reference: https://github.com/RamVegiraju/SageMaker-Deployment/tree/master/RealTime/Script-Mode/Sklearn/Regression

Comment: The train channel was not specified correctly in the end it worked fine :) just had an embarrassing typo :/